# regex: match number sequences without matching previous matches

Tags: regex

I am looking through number sequences of 3 comma-delimited values and want to search for any sequence of `1,2,3`. I want to match `1,2,3`; `3,2,1`; `2,1,3`; etc. I do NOT want to match `1,1,1`; `1,2,2`; `1,3,3`; `3,3,1`; `2,3,3`; using regexr.com for my regex parsing.

```
[123],[123],[123]
```

is what I started with until I realized it matched any character and not sequence of characters.

I was researching positive/negative lookaheads but could not think of how to structure it logically so the regex would not match a previously matched number in the specified sequence.

What fundamental thing am I missing here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a lookahead and back-reference based regex:

```
([123]),((?!\1)[123]),((?!\1|\2)[123])
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wQ3vV5/4)

**RegEx Breakup:**

```
([123])          # match 1 or 2 or 3 and capture it in group #1
,                # match literal comma
((?!\1)[123])    # match 1 or 2 or 3 if it is NOT same as group #1 & capture it in group #2
,                # match literal comma
((?!\1|\2)[123]) # match 1 or 2 or 3 if it is NOT same as group #1 OR #2
```

Comment: Your second lookahead should be `(?!\1|\2)`, or you'll match things like `1,2,1` or `3,1,3`.  The OP didn't include examples like those, but I'm pretty sure he doesn't want to match them.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanations, I had started piecing together something with the "([123]),((?!\1)" model but it was beyond me to figure out the correct syntax. Thank you @Alan Moore for correcting his answer, you are correct that I do not want to match your last examples.

Comment: I had tried this in Google Sheets's REGEXMATCH function which apparently only supports RE2 engine regex. Did a bit of research and I believe our current engine this is using is RegExp based off of JavaScript?

Comment: I apologize for the late edit, but it seems this regex is not matching a sequence of 2,1,2 with ([122]),((?!\1)[122]),((?!\1|\2)[122])

Comment: Why should 2,1,2 be a match when 2 is being repeated twice?

Comment: Also to leave a comment you don't need to remove the tick mark.

Comment: If you want to avoid matching only just previous number then will [`([123]),((?!\1)[123]),((?!\2)[123])`](https://regex101.com/r/wQ3vV5/5) work for you? It was my first answer as well before Alan's comment.

Comment: anubhava, thank you for your continued patience with my question. The `[123]` characters are dynamic. They are not always `123`. Your corrected answer from Alan worked great until I had to match a sequence of `1,2,2`, which should match any order of those numbers, so it should match `1,2,2; 2,1,2; 2,2,1;`. I am dynamically changing the specified characters in the brackets `[]`.

Comment: If requirements change it is better to ask a new question to get much better answers rather than editing the question and un-accepting the older one (where you get only person's attention :-)).

Comment: Besides now I don't even understand the question because `1,2,2` has digit  `2` repeating twice so it shouldn't be a match.

Comment: I was unclear in my question, I specifically asked for searching for sequences of `1,2,3` thinking I could use the regex dynamically for ANY sequence matching. When I changed your answer from `([123]),((?!\1)[123]),((?!\1|\2)[123])` to `([122]),((?!\1)[122]),((?!\1|\2)[122])` in an attempt to search for any sequence of `1,2,2` it failed. That's what I get for assuming :) How shall we proceed? Rename the question/un-edit my edit and mark your answer again then ask a new question?

Comment: Before I ask a new question I am going to give a crack at the regex myself, after doing some more research I will need two separate regex depending on the sequence I am looking for. So, if my sequence to search for has two of the same integers, like `1,2,2` it will be different from your answer. If my sequence has unique integers like `1,2,3` or `4,5,6` then your answer is perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Answer#1 is @anubhava's solution, his solution correctly matches any sequence as long as all 3 integers are unique. However, in a situation where the sequence to search for has 2 repeated integers, you use the following regex, assuming your sequence to search for is `1,2,2`. Can't believe I made it this hard :P

`((1,2,2)|(2,1,2)|(2,2,1))`

I realised that in a situation of 2 repeated integers, only 3 possible matches are available. So, instead of trying to build a complex lookbehind/lookahead regex we can simply search for those three occurrences literally. Using the capture groups should tag what it matched.

Obviously, in a sequence of 3 repeated integers such as `3,3,3` there is only one possible match so you search for it literally.